# Which test to choose?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

As you may have guessed from the title, I am very confused as to which statistical test I should use for my data.

So I have 15 individuals, for each of them I have several ( from 1 to 20) measures of the time they spent foraging. I also have two conditions, lets say A and B, under which the individuals foraged.

What I need to know is whether the individuals have been spending more time in condition A than in condition B.

It would be very nice if I could obtain an overall result, for example, if all the individuals spent globally more time foraging in condition A than in condition B.

I would also need a more detailed result, and knowing which individual did spend more time foraging in condition A than B, or if some of them did the opposite.

I would be very grateful if I could some advices as to which test would achieve what I aim for.

Comment: You can use a mixed effects model, with `foraging time` being explained by `condition` (as fixed effect) and `individual` (as random intercept). In `R`, this would be `lmer(foraging_time ~ condition + (1|individual))`. This would address your first question, but your second one would be a bit more complicated. I'll let someone more knowledgeable chime in to address that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a linear mixed model (LMM) with the condition as fixed effect and the individual as a random offset. You can also include a random slope if you think some individuals exhibit a larger difference in foraging time between the two conditions.

The significance of the fixed effect will reveal if the condition has an effect on the mean foraging time. Closer scrutiny of the estimated values of the random effects will allow you to understand differences between the species, apart from the mean trend.